# Selecionar linhas de uma tabela com as setas do teclado

Tags: vue.js

estou tentando desenvolver um código para conseguir navegar entre as linhas de uma tabela html usando as setas de navegação.

qual seria a melhor forma? eu preciso que a linha selecionada fique com um classe diferente.

meu codigo está assim:

```
           <tr v-for="(item, index) in itens_adicionados">
                    <td class="text-right">{{ item.item }}</td>
                    <td class="text-right">{{ item.codigo }}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="text-right">{{ item.descricao }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{ item.quantidade }}</td>
                    <td class="text-right">{{ item.valor_unitario }}</td>
                    <td class="text-right">{{ item.valor_total }}</td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Cara posso estar errado, mas, uma tabela não é um elemento estático, para poder navegar pelas teclas teria quer ser editável não?!

Answer (score 0):

Há várias maneiras de fazer isso. Deixo uma sugestão que escuta na janela toda por eventos `keydown` e especificamente pelas teclas para cima e baixo.

Podes também limitar a um elemento e usar os ganchos/hooks to Vue com `@keyup.up="changeRow(-1)"` se preferires. A vantagem é que não precisas limpar o auscultador com  `removeEventListener` a desvantagem é que para esse hook do Vue funcionar o foco da página tem de estar dentro do elemento que tem o `keyup.up`.

Exemplo:

```js
const dataArray = [{
    number: 0,
    text: 'foo'
  },
  {
    number: 1,
    text: 'bar'
  },
  {
    number: 2,
    text: 'baz'
  }
];

const getRowIncrement = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 38) return -1;
  if (e.keyCode === 40) return 1;
  return 0;
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    linha: 0,
    tableData: dataArray,
  },
  methods: {
    changeRow(e) {
      const rowIncrement = getRowIncrement(e);
      if (!rowIncrement) return;
      
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      this.linha = (this.linha + rowIncrement + this.tableData.length) % this.tableData.length;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.changeRow);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.changeRow);
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.chosen {
  background-color: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="line in tableData" :key="line.number" :class="line.number === linha ? 'chosen' : ''">
      <td v-for="prop in line" :key="prop">{{prop}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```